# Ctags include extern functions as function prototype?

Tags: vim, ctags, omnicppcomplete

I'm a newbie using vim as an IDE for C.
I have installed c-vim, omnicppcompletion, ctags and other useful plugins.

However omnicppcompetion is based on the ctags database,
but it seems that ctags can't deal with functions like read/write/socket well.

I built my tags using the following command in my Arch box:
    `$ pacman -Qql glibc | grep \.h$ > /tmp/filelist_c ; ctags  -L /tmp/filelist_c  --c-kinds=+px --fields=+iaS --extra=+q`

However functions like write,socket are not in the tags.
I know these functions are extern functions in the header files, but only the argument list and function are needed to do the completion and even extern functions have enough info for me.

Any idea about making tags which also include extern functions?

Answer (score 4):

Header files `*.h` is known by `ctags` as `C++` files, so, the easiest way to achieve what you need is to add the following option to ctags command line:

`--c++-kinds=+p+l`

And, well, why not to use plugin [Indexer](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation) that was made especially for managing the ctags in Vim?

Comment: Thanks, but add --c++-kinds=+p+l does not work either.I'll try indexer

Comment: It should work, I just tested it. I created file `test.h` with the following contents: `extern void my_func(int a, int b);` , and I executed ctags by the following command: `ctags --c++-kinds=+p ./test.h`.  The resulting tags file contains the following line: `my_func ./test.h /^extern void my_func(int a, int b);$/;" p
`

Comment: Sorry, I know this should work. But what I need is to complete system calls like socket(),connect(). User defined functions are already working for me even without any additional ctags paramentors.

Comment: I had the same issue with socket.h and your answer solved it, but I still don't understand what you did there, I am looking for --c++-kinds on the doc and not having any luck. Can you please tell me what that is doing?